# Как добавить кнопку выбрать все рубрики/категории в админку?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите куда копать, гугл результатов не выдает, либо я ищу не там

нужно сделать кнопку, чтобы по нажатию были отмечены все категории[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [Krya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/243545/krya) за наводку. С javascript на вы, стыдно такое показывать. Сделал такое для себя решение.

```
        <div style="display: block; padding:20px 0px;">
            <label for="checkAll_taxonomies" >
                <button id="checkAll_taxonomies" type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="setTrueAllCheckBoxes()">Выбрать все</button>
            </label>
            <label for="checkAll_taxonomies">
                <button id="checkAll_taxonomies" type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="setFalseAllCheckBoxes()">Снять все</button>
            </label>
        </div>
        <script>
            function setTrueAllCheckBoxes() {
                let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tax_input[<?= $tax_name ?>][]");
                for (let index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                    if(checkboxes[index].checked === false) {
                        checkboxes[index].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            function setFalseAllCheckBoxes() {
                let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tax_input[<?= $tax_name ?>][]");
                for (let index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                    if(checkboxes[index].checked === true) {
                        checkboxes[index].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

шаблон скопировал из post_categories_meta_box и создал свою функцию в functions и вставил туда код сверху

```
function get_all_categories_box( $post, $box ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
    if ( ! isset( $box['args'] ) || ! is_array( $box['args'] ) ) {
        $args = array();
    } else {
        $args = $box['args'];
    }
    $parsed_args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $tax_name    = esc_attr( $parsed_args['taxonomy'] );
    $taxonomy    = get_taxonomy( $parsed_args['taxonomy'] );

    // Вкладки категории/часто используемые - tabs
    ?>
    <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="categorydiv">
        <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-tabs" class="category-tabs">
            <li class="tabs"><a href="#<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-all"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->all_items; ?></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hide-if-no-js"><a
                        href="#<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-pop"><?php echo esc_html( $taxonomy->labels->most_used ); ?></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <?php
        // вкладка часто используемые
        ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-pop" class="tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
            <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>checklist-pop" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php $popular_ids = wp_popular_terms_checklist( $tax_name ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php
        // вкладка категорий
        ?>

        <div style="display: block; padding:20px 0px;">
            <label for="checkAll_taxonomies" >
                <button id="checkAll_taxonomies" type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="setTrueAllCheckBoxes()">Выбрать все</button>
            </label>
            <label for="checkAll_taxonomies">
                <button id="checkAll_taxonomies" type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="setFalseAllCheckBoxes()">Снять все</button>
            </label>
        </div>
        <script>
            function setTrueAllCheckBoxes() {
                let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tax_input[<?= $tax_name ?>][]");
                for (let index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                    if(checkboxes[index].checked === false) {
                        checkboxes[index].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            function setFalseAllCheckBoxes() {
                let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("tax_input[<?= $tax_name ?>][]");
                for (let index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
                    if(checkboxes[index].checked === true) {
                        checkboxes[index].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

        <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-all" class="tabs-panel">
            <?php
            $name = ( $tax_name == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $tax_name . ']';
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />"; // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
            ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"
                class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php
                wp_terms_checklist(
                    $post->ID,
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $tax_name,
                        'popular_cats' => $popular_ids,
                    )
                );
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy->cap->edit_terms ) ) : ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-adder" class="wp-hidden-children">
                <a id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-add-toggle" href="#<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-add"
                   class="hide-if-no-js taxonomy-add-new">
                    <?php
                    /* translators: %s: Add New taxonomy label. */
                    printf( __( '+ %s' ), $taxonomy->labels->add_new_item );
                    ?>
                </a>
                <p id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-add" class="category-add wp-hidden-child">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text"
                           for="new<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->add_new_item; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="new<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" id="new<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"
                           class="form-required form-input-tip"
                           value="<?php echo esc_attr( $taxonomy->labels->new_item_name ); ?>" aria-required="true"/>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="new<?php echo $tax_name; ?>_parent">
                        <?php echo $taxonomy->labels->parent_item_colon; ?>
                    </label>
                    <?php
                    $parent_dropdown_args = array(
                        'taxonomy'         => $tax_name,
                        'hide_empty'       => 0,
                        'name'             => 'new' . $tax_name . '_parent',
                        'orderby'          => 'name',
                        'hierarchical'     => 1,
                        'show_option_none' => '&mdash; ' . $taxonomy->labels->parent_item . ' &mdash;',
                    );
                    $parent_dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'post_edit_category_parent_dropdown_args', $parent_dropdown_args );

                    wp_dropdown_categories( $parent_dropdown_args );
                    ?>
                    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-add-submit"
                           data-wp-lists="add:<?php echo $tax_name; ?>checklist:<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-add"
                           class="button category-add-submit"
                           value="<?php echo esc_attr( $taxonomy->labels->add_new_item ); ?>"/>
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-' . $tax_name, '_ajax_nonce-add-' . $tax_name, false ); ?>
                    <span id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-ajax-response"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

и добавил имя функции в register_taxonomy в поле meta_box_cb

```
register_taxonomy(
        'hireo_brands',
        array(
            'hireo_service',
            'hireo_shop',
            'hireo_technique',
        ),
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'          => 'Бренды',
                'singular_name' => 'Бренд',
            ),
            'meta_box_cb'  => 'get_all_categories_box',
        )
    );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

При регистрации таксономии есть параметр: `meta_box_cb`, который отвечает за вывод этого метабокса. Вы можете добавить туда свой `callback` взяв за основу `post_categories_meta_box`.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю отпишусь